# How do I specify a regex in Java to match any IP address that does not end in ".0.0"?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to validate that a String field (representing an IP address) in an object does not end in `.0.0`. I will be using the [@Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation to perform the validation.

I tried the following:

```
@Pattern(regexp="(?!(\\.0\\.0$))", message="IP address must not end in .0.0")
private String ipAddress;
```

This correctly printed out the validation error message for 192.168.0.0. However, it incorrectly printed out the validation error message for valid IP addresses like 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.0.

What regex pattern would achieve what I want?

Comment: If there are only 4 blocks of digits `^(?!\\d+\\.\\d+\\.0\\.0$)`

Comment: There's probably some way to do this, but it seems ugly.  Why do you not want to validate IP addresses like 192.168.0.0?  Those *are* valid IP addresses, they're not special or reserved or anything.

Comment: One nice trick if you only want to check something about the end of the string is to reverse it and then check the beginning. So, reverse the string with the IP address and then check if it begins with `"0.0."`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird When I do `java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^(?!\\d+\\.\\d+\\.0\\.0$)");` and then call `pattern.matcher("192.168.1.1").matches()`, it incorrectly returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a tutorial on negative look ahead that seems to do what you want:

```
REGEX: \d+\.\d+\.(?!0\.0)\d+\.\d+
```

You'll have to add extra slashes for a Java string.  (I tested this on an old "REGEX Tester" program I made in 2016 or so, no code was harmed in the making of that regex.)

The short explanation is "negative look ahead" is used to invalidate a string of "0.0".  The regex finds the first two digit strings (`\d+\.\d+\.`) then "looks ahead" without updating the current position for the string "0.0" `(?!0\.0)`.  If it finds that string, then it invalidates the match, because it's *negative* look ahead, which only matches if it *doesn't* find the string. If it doesn't find the string then we just go on to match the final two octets as normal.

(As DuncG and pacoverflow point out below, there might be some ways to improve this.  Using `(?!0+\.0+$)` for the negative look ahead is probably a better idea.  And don't forget to wrap this regex in `^( )$`.)

I think there's several ways for this to go wrong however and I think I'd recommend a full IP address parser (what about IPV6 addresses?) and then testing the octets/16-bit numbers as numbers, not strings.

The website: https://regexland.com/regex-match-all-except/

Comment: Nice way to use regex though as you say there are some edge case problems such as "192.168.00.00", easily fixed with adding `+` after the zeroes.

Comment: I also tweaked it to be `^\d+\.\d+\.(?!0+\.0+$)\d+\.\d+$` to handle 192.168.00.01.

Comment: I'll update, thanks for pointing this out!